# Javascript code not working unless there are no spaces. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Ok so I am running into a really weird bug on my Wordpress site that hope is just my ignorance because this just seems too weird.

So I am working with styling a couple of input tags as well as a ReCaptcha form. I found some documentation at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization that I have been following. Basically what I want is the clean theme listed at that link and to do some showing/hiding of the captcha based on certain events.

I do realize that the top of the article mentions this version of the api is old, but the plugin I am using has some recaptcha code entangled in their code, so I figured I would try this first instead of making major modifications to the plugin.

So here is the code I am using

```
<!-- Code added by me-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean'
 };
function toggleCaptcha(inputField)
{
alert('working');
}
</script>
<!-- End code added by me -->

<script>
function validateGoodNewsUser(frm, requireName) {
    requireName = requireName || false;

    if(requireName && frm.goodnews_name.value=="") {
        alert("Please provide name");
        frm.goodnews_name.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(frm.email.value=="" || frm.email.value.indexOf("@")<1 || frm.email.value.indexOf(".")<1) {
        alert("Please provide a valid email address");
        frm.email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // check custom fields
    var req_cnt = frm.elements["required_fields[]"].length; // there's always at least 1
    if(req_cnt > 1) {
        for(i = 0; i<req_cnt; i++) {
            var fieldName = frm.elements["required_fields[]"][i].value;
            if(fieldName !='') {
                var isFilled = false;
                // ignore radios
                if(frm.elements[fieldName].type == 'radio') continue;

                // checkbox
                if(frm.elements[fieldName].type == 'checkbox' && !frm.elements[fieldName].checked) {
                    alert("This field is required");
                    frm.elements[fieldName].focus();
                    return false;
                }       

                // all other fields
                if(frm.elements[fieldName].value=="") {
                    alert("This field is required");
                    frm.elements[fieldName].focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
<form method="post" class="goodnews-front-form" onsubmit="return validateGoodNewsUser(this,false);">
    <div><label>Your Name:</label> <input type="text" name="goodnews_name"></div>
    <div><label>*Your Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" onfocus="toggleCaptcha(this)"></div>       



    <p><script type="text/javascript" src="<!--Captcha api url here-->"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="<!--Captcha api url here-->" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript></p> 
    <div><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">     
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="goodnews_subscribe" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="required_fields[]" value="">
</form>
```

So the problem I am running into is when I load the page, I see the clean theme for ReCaptcha and the alert shows up when I click inside the input box for the email. But if I change my added code by adding a single space like this

```
<!-- Code added by me-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean'
};
                                      <<<<<<<< Single new line space added.
function toggleCaptcha(inputField)
{
alert('working');
}
</script>
```

The whole thing breaks and the page loads with the standard red ReCaptcha and my functions don't get called.

I don't mind not using spaces, but that seems very odd that a space would make the difference. Am I missing something here? Is this caused by the outdated api?

Edit:

I was asked to try to get a jsfiddle working (or not working???). I stripped out everything except the form and the function call. Even the ReCaptcha was taken out and I still can not get it to call the function. This may be my lack of knowledge on jsfiddle or it may get closer to the real problem. https://jsfiddle.net/b257779t/

Comment: That *is* very odd. Do you get any errors in the browser's console? Can you reproduce this problem at a site we can access? (e.g., can you create a cut-down demo at http://jsfiddle.net or something?)

Comment: Yeah I am working on that right now.

Comment: Did you copy and paste some part of your code into this JS? It might probably contain any unwanted characters.

Comment: I did copy the js bit from the google api link originally, but at one point got fed up and started from scratch. The second time I typed everything from the link without copying.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to make it call the function, but... 1) I don't see what the fiddle has to do with the problem in the question (since it doesn't contain the problematic bits) and 2) Please don't ever do that again, produce an alert on focus. Because the alert takes the focus away. Closing the alert gives the focus back. Shudder.

Comment: The problem is the function does not get called. I had a hunch that it was because of the ReCaptcha api, but even after removing everything related to ReCaptcha, the problem still persisted. Hense the almost empty jsfiddle.

Comment: Was the jsfiddle updated? I just checked and it still doesn't call the function (meaning the shudder problem does not occur).

Comment: If needed I can try to set up something in a dummy Wordpress account so you can see the ReCaptcha stuff included and the original state of my problem. Although I can do that, if stripping it all out does not fix the issue I doubt it is related.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the link. Here is the updated fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/b257779t/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/b257779t/1/). the problem was that by default, JSFiddle puts the JavaScript block in an onload wrapper. I put it directly in the head.